# Why is this code not working?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to take such a output like;

```
$ sh mod-date-pattern.sh sun
The file sun1.txt was modified on 2007-10-01 at 01:26.
The file sun2.txt was modified on 2007-10-01 at 19:10.
The file morning-sun.txt was modified on 2007-10-01 at 02:53.
The file evening-sun.txt was modified on 2007-10-01 at 02:55.
```

And my code is ;

```
Namefile=$1
ExDatefile=$(ls -l $Namefile*)
IFS=' ' array_Datefile=($Exdatefile)
for n in 5 14 22 30 
do 
m=$(($n +1))
o=$(($m +1))
p=$(($n -3))
Mounth=${array_Datefile[$n]}
Day=${array_Datefile[$m]}
Time=${array_Datefile[$o]}
Name=${array_Datefile[$p]}
echo "The file $Name was modified on $Mounth $Day $Time"
done
```

By the way **the output of $ExDatefile** is ;

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 onurcanbektas staff 2026 May 29 2008 hw1_evening_sun.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 onurcanbektas staff 2687 May 29 2008 hw1_morning_sun.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 onurcanbektas staff 243128 May 29 2008 hw1_out_si_wire.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 onurcanbektas staff 282 Jun 2 10:28 hw1_script.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 onurcanbektas staff 68 Jun 2 11:49 hw1_script2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 onurcanbektas staff 577 May 29 2008 hw1_sun1.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 onurcanbektas staff 6074 May 29 2008 hw1_sun2.txt
```

And the output is;

```
$ sh hw1_script2.sh hw1
The file  was modified on   
The file  was modified on   
The file  was modified on   
The file  was modified on
```

So , what is wrong ?

Note:I am not sure whether the information given is enough for answering this question.If it is the case , please inform me.

Bash 3.2 OS X El Capitan

**Edit**:

when I directly call $array_Datefile[$n] , the output is;

```
[5] [6] [7] [8]
[14] [15] [16] [17]
[22] [23] [24] [25]
[30] [31] [32] [33]
```

Why is it like that ?Are there any problem with parsing ?

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Use `stat` or `find ... -printf` or anything else instead.

Comment: @cas I understand why I shouldn't parse but I've started to learn shell script recently ,so I couldn't understand how I should do .

Comment: If you're a beginner then now is the **perfect** time to avoid learning bad habits.

Comment: The modification date from `ls -l`  is not consistent with your goal. Even if you use `ls -lT` your script will fail if file names have spaces in them. I strongly suggest that you read the manuals `stat` and `strftime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it ;

```
Namefile=$1
i=-1
for n in $Namefile*
do
ExDatefile=$(ls -l $Namefile* | head $i | tail -1 )
i=$(($i -1))
IFS=' ' array_Datefile=($ExDatefile)
echo "The file ${array_Datefile[8]} was modified ${array_Datefile[5]} ${array_D$
unset ExDatefile
done
```

The output is ;

```
The file hw1_evening_sun.txt was modified May 29 2008
The file hw1_morning_sun.txt was modified May 29 2008
The file hw1_out_si_wire.txt was modified May 29 2008
The file hw1_script.sh was modified Jun 2 15:20
The file hw1_script2.sh was modified Jun 2 15:16
The file hw1_sun1.txt was modified May 29 2008
The file hw1_sun2.txt was modified May 29 2008
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you really want to parse `ls -l` output, you could try this:

```
Namefile=$1
while read perms blocks user group size month day yearortime filename ;do
    echo "The file $filename was modified on $month $day $yearortime"
  done < <(ls -l $Namefile*)
```

... but if `for $Namefile* ..` you'd better:

```
Namefile=$1
for file in $Namefile*;do
    unixtime=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
    printf "The file %s was modified on %(%b %d %Y, %T)T\n" "$file" $unixtime
  done
```

Comment: With BSD stat you could just use- `stat -f 'The file %N was modified on %Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d at %R' -- "$file"` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be complete, but $(ls -l xxx) produces a single line, not a line per file.  That messes up your parsing.

So, loop over $Namefile*, dealing with a single file at a time.

Comment: I know $(ls -l xxx) gives a single line .In fact, the numbers in loop are gives the modification date of an every single file .I still don't understand how it messes up.

Comment: By the way , I also didn't understand what do you mean by "loop over $Namefile* " ?

Answer (score 0):

You got the indices wrong:

```
for ((m = 5; m < ${#array_Datefile[@]}; m += 9))
do
    d=$((m + 1))
    t=$((m + 2))
    f=$((m + 3))
    Month=${array_Datefile[m]}
    Day=${array_Datefile[d]}
    Time=${array_Datefile[t]}
    Name=${array_Datefile[f]}
    echo "The file $Name was modified on $Month $Day $Time"
done
```

Comment: The code surprisingly doesn't give any output :)

Comment: I realized now , statement of "for" is not suitable.